# Airflow Worker Configuration

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am a newbie to Airflow. I'm trying to setup Distributed Mode of Airflow Using Celery Executor by Refering this article https://stlong0521.github.io/20161023%20-%20Airflow.html

Before getting into detail about the specification I would like to confirm that **I've installed PostgreSQL on a seperate instance**.

The specification of the setup is detailed below:

**Airflow core/server computer**

- Python 3.5

  - airflow (AIRFLOW_HOME = ~/airflow)
  - celery
  - psycogp2
- RabbitMQ

**Configurations made in airflow.cfg**:

```
sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql+psycopg2://username:password@192.168.2.12:5432/airflow
executor = CeleryExecutor
broker_url = amqp://username:password@192.168.1.12:5672//
celery_result_backend = db+postgresql://username:password@192.168.2.12:5432/airflow
```

Tests performed:

```
RabbitMQ is running
Can connect to PostgreSQL and have confirmed that Airflow has created tables
Can start and view the webserver (including custom dags)
```

**Airflow worker computer**

Has the following installed:

- Python 3.5 with

  - airflow (AIRFLOW_HOME = ~/airflow)
  - celery
- psycogp2

Configurations made in airflow.cfg are exactly the same as in the server:

```
sql_alchemy_conn = postgresql+psycopg2://username:password@192.168.2.12:5432/airflow
executor = CeleryExecutor
broker_url = amqp://username:password@192.168.1.12:5672//
celery_result_backend = db+postgresql://username:password@192.168.2.12:5432/airflow
```

Output from commands run on the worker machine:

When running airflow flower:

```
[2018-02-19 14:58:14,276] {__init__.py:57} INFO - Using executor CeleryExecutor
[2018-02-19 14:58:14,360] {driver.py:120} INFO - Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.5/lib2to3/Grammar.txt
[2018-02-19 14:58:14,384] {driver.py:120} INFO - Generating grammar tables from /usr/lib/python3.5/lib2to3/PatternGrammar.txt
[I 180219 14:58:15 command:139] Visit me at http://0.0.0.0:5555
[I 180219 14:58:15 command:144] Broker: amqp://username:password@192.168.1.12:5672//
[I 180219 14:58:15 command:147] Registered tasks: 
    ['celery.accumulate',
     'celery.backend_cleanup',
     'celery.chain',
     'celery.chord',
     'celery.chord_unlock',
     'celery.chunks',
     'celery.group',
     'celery.map',
     'celery.starmap']
[I 180219 14:58:15 mixins:224] Connected to amqp://username:password@192.168.1.12:5672//
```

I am passing the dag in the **Airflow Core machine** and also I have copied the sample data(Excel sheets) which the dag will process to the same core machine.

My worker log 
`raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'airflow run dag_name_x task_name_xx 2018-02-19T10:15:41.657243 --local -sd /home/Distributedici/airflow/dags/sample_data_xx.py' returned non-zero exit status 1`

**Now my query is**

1) Should I copy the dag folder to the worker computer also

2) Right now, I have not copied the dag folder on the worker computer and I'm not able to see the worker process pick up the task.

Please point me where I am making a mistake and how to make the worker process pick up the process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your configuration files look okay. As you suspected, all workers do indeed require a copy of the DAG folder. You can use something like `git` to keep them in sync and up to date.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. Ya I tried placing the DAG folder in the worker instance too.. Still it did not work. Finally I understood that I not only required to copy the DAG folder, I need to change the **fernet_key of the worker** as that of the **scheduler** for it to work.

Comment: Yeah I would suggest keeping your config identical across scheduler/workers/webserver.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you did to resolve your issue? What do you mean you just changed the fernet_key of the worker?

Comment: i've an aws ec2 instance up and running for airflow-docker. Now I would like to upgrade the same to airflow-docker-swarm for scalability. Can you guyz give some pointers around the same?

Answer (score 5):

Some of the biggest pain points with Airflow come up around deployment and keeping DAG files and plugins in sync across your Airflow scheduler, Airflow webserver, and Celery worker nodes.

We've created an open source project called [Astronomer Open](https://github.com/astronomerio/astronomer) that automates a Dockerized Airflow, Celery, and PostgreSQL with some other goodies baked in.  The project was motivated by seeing so many people hit the same pain points creating a very similar setup.

For example, here's the Airflow Dockerfile: https://github.com/astronomer/astronomer/blob/master/docker/airflow/1.10.2/Dockerfile

And the docs: https://open.astronomer.io/

Full disclosure: This is a project I contribute to at work — we offer a paid [enterprise edition](https://www.astronomer.io/) as well that runs on Kubernetes [(docs)](https://enterprise.astronomer.io/).  That said, the Open Edition is totally free to use.

Comment: this doesn't seem to be open source any more

Comment: @deontologician It looks like the location of the Dockerfiles has changed but they are still open source.  https://github.com/astronomer/astronomer/tree/master/docker/airflow.  You can also use the Astro CLI locally for an easy quickstart experience.  https://www.astronomer.io/docs/cli-quickstart

Comment: If one has taken the Docker path already, it might be easier to use Airflow's new [`DockerSwarmOperator`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_docker_swarm_operator.py) to scale Airflow DAGs across multiple nodes.

Comment: @akki Thank you for authoring this addition with [#5489](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/5489/files) — it looks pretty cool.  Is the problem it solves (vs DockerOperator) running Docker containers representing Airflow task instances on a remote Docker daemon that exists outside of your Airflow worker nodes?

Comment: @TaylorEdmiston I have not tested it with a remote Docker daemon myself but from [this comment](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/5489#issuecomment-520485656) on the PR I understand it is possible. The operator itself gives you the ability to run Airflow tasks on a server which doesn't even run Airflow (but is a part of a Docker swarm cluster). Docker Swarm is Docker's native orchestration tool - basically you have a bunch of servers running Docker (and Airflow should be running on one of them), then this operator runs your task on any of those servers which has enough resources.

Comment: @akki Thanks, this is a really cool idea to integrate Airflow with Docker Swarm.  With the Swarm cluster being agnostic of Airflow, it sounds like it could have less overhead than running many `DockerOperator`s inside the Airflow workers directly.  I look forward to trying it!

Comment: Thanks. If you have any constructive feedback/suggestions, I would love to hear. :)

Answer (score 1):

A little late on this, but it might still help someone, as from the existing answers it looks like there is no way to share DAGs other then "manual" deployment (via git/scp etc.), while there is a way.

Airflow supports [pickling](https://airflow.apache.org/cli.html#run) (`-p` parameter from the CLI or `command: scheduler -p` in your docker-compose file), which allows to deploy the DAGs on the server/master, and have them serialized and sent to the workers (so you don't have to deploy DAGs in multiple places and you avoid issues with out-of-sync DAGs).

Pickling is compatible with `CeleryExecutor`.

Pickling has some limitations that can bite you back, notably the actual code of classes and functions is not serialized (only the fully qualified name is), so there will be an error if you try to deserialize a DAG referring to code you don't have in the target environment. For more info on pickle you can have a look here: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/pickle.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, dags must be present on all airflow nodes - worker, webserver, scheduler.

You can have a cron that runs git pull in your dags folder on all nodes to keep it in sync.

Airflow will move all dags to database instead of file system - this feature might come in 2.0.